# Google Map not loaded?.. Is anyone faced this issue?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I Worked Many times in google map.. But newly facing this issue..
IS anyone faced issue like this?
I searched many times but wasn't get a good solution..

build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
```

Mainfest.xml

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="My API KEY" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

> Logcat

```
03-06 16:07:38.902 10306-10306/I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 10298000
03-06 16:07:38.942 10306-10306/ I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 10298446
```

Comment: Update Google play services.

Comment: Update Google Play Services in My android-sdk right..

Comment: But I already updated..

Comment: Are u using emulator or device.

Comment: In emulator it's working without any issue.. But in device the map wasn't load..

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Downgrade the version of google play services in your gradle to 9.6.0

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

dont change this
"compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
did you get the Key and insert it in Manifest.xml ?
Make sure that your google play services is already updating

Comment: I tried all the methods.. I'm not new to android.. But, this issue sucks my time and work..

Comment: Me too a have many probleme but the GoogleMap work for me that why i want to help you
Did u show as ur code ?

Comment: Google map working when u use emulator or USB Debugging with Mobile.. But Generate the APK and installed it.. Now the map not loading..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your api keys do not match any longer. Your `google-services.json` might have been updated by the Firebase plugin to no longer match the keys specified at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials.

I had to match value of `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY` to google-services.json

```
    {
          "current_key": "AIzaxxxxxxxx..."
    }
```

Also you should be able to remove

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

from your manifest, since google maps does not seem to need it any longer. You can also replace `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY` with `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` according to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup